# Insert new user into DB

Tags: sql

I'm just trying to insert a new user into a database only if the user's id does not already exist.

I can't seem to figure it out.

The data given is just the user_id, password. I want to insert this data into the database only if the user_id does not already exist.

How?

If your answer isn't self-explanatory, please explain what is going on.

All I want is to be able to insert into a new customer into database Customers from W3schools only if there isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Are you using any other languages besides some sort of SQL for this?

Comment: Add UNIQUE CONSTRAINT for the user_id column. If there is an error on insert the user already exists.

Comment: Did you even try to google this before posting a question.  There are plenty of resources that address your question.  Also , what is ur platform ?  Look at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-user.html

Comment: Are you talking about an **application** user (i.e., inserting some data in to a table you created) or creating a **database** user? What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using SQL SERVER, you can simply add a select statement to verify if the user exists before proceeding;

```
If not Exists (select loginname from master.dbo.syslogins 
    where name = @loginName and dbname = 'YOUR_DB_NAME')
Begin

-- Insert statement here 

End
```

Comment: Not sure what is going on. All I want to do is just insert a new customer into the Customers DB from W3schools SQL editor.http://www.w3schools.com/sql/